# Agrupar listas en Dataframe de pandas y realizar conteo

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Quiero crear un nuevo Dataframe agrupando las listas de un df anterior y añadiendo un contador de las veces que se repiten (las listas). Para que quede más claro:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_excel('Archivo.xlsx')
```

El DataFrame de partida es:

```
df1= 
    Alfanum   Numero  
0   1256ADL        1
1   3789BQP        3
2   7382BCD        2
3   9367CDF        1
4   9737AHH        1
5   3789BQP        5
6   7382BCD        5
```

Creo un segundo DataFrame que agrupa

```
df2 = df1.groupby("Alfanum")["Numero"].apply(list)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2).reset_index()
```

```
df2= 
    Alfanum      Numero  
0   1256ADL      [1]
1   3789BQP      [3, 5]
2   7382BCD      [2, 5]  
3   9367CDF      [1]
4   9737AHH      [1]
```

Por último, quiero establecer un contador en función de la columna número, de manera que quede algo como:

```
df3= 
    Numero     Contador 
0      [1]          3
1   [3, 5]          1
2   [2, 5]          1
```

He intentado de la siguiente manera y me devuelve TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
df3 = df2.groupby(['Alfanum']).size().reset_index(name='Contador')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Python las listas no son elementos "hashables", es decir, no es posible asociarle un "hash" (un número único) a cada elemento de la lista, que es lo que necesita hacer en primer lugar el `group_by`. La solución podría ser convertir estas listas en tuplas que si son "hasheables":

```
df2.Numero = df2.Numero.apply(lambda x: tuple(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x)
print(df2.groupby(['Numero']).size())

Numero
(1,)      3
(2, 5)    1
(3, 5)    1
dtype: int64
```